# how to add PKCS7 padding to rijndael.h?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have a rijndael.cpp and rijndael.h code. There is no padding. i would lik to add pkcs7. how to do that?
I am working with aes256

Here is the code for rijndael.h and .cpp: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidD199709122D7F7FC8E12D4159FC14F0F037CA58E.aspx?s=%22Marc+Richarme%22. Can someone please help me to make a test. I need to have an ecryption aes 256 with cbc and padding PKCS7. THX.

Answer (score 1):

You should at the padding by yourself to the end of your data. It is quite simple, you can read details about PKCS#7 data here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29

Comment: thx for tha answer. The thing is the result using the rijndale and openssl is not the same.can i post the code?